# embed blob pdf doesnt work in IE and Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, blob, embed, microsoft-edge

this part of code works fine in Chrome, but in IE and Edge, it doesn't.

HTML

```
<object id="pdfObject" ng-hide="$ctrl.item == false" data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="height: 100%;width: 100%;padding-bottom: 40px;">

<embed id="pdfEmbed" ng-src="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="height: 100%;width: 100%;"/></object>
```

JS

```
 var file = new Blob([this.item], { type: 'application/pdf' });
 var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
 $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL)
```

this.item has response from HTTP call.

Comment: "does not work".... try turning off IE's ActiveX Filtering. Tools>ActiveX filtering. Set up IE to record blocked content and security messages in the dev tool console... Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. PDF documents are hosted in a ActiveX control in IE... chrome uses a built-in plugin... from IE use Tools>Manage Addons>Show all addons to manage your PDF viewer addon.

Comment: lol i dont want that kind of solution...

Comment: Any other solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the embed tag the property src should be filled with the url of blob file, change content to fileURL variable and should be fixed

```
var file = new Blob([this.item], { type: 'application/pdf' });
$scope.fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file); //here is the change
$scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL)
```

and

```
<embed id="pdfEmbed" src="{{fileURL}}" type="application/pdf" style="height: 100%;width: 100%;"/>
```

the thing is $sce.trustAsResourceUrl is returning an object and that doesnt match to a src